# how to pack phonegap blackberry application with a video?

Tags: html, cordova, blackberry

I am developing application for blackberry using phonegap.
I have a requirement to display video in my application.
I want to package my application with the video.
I copied my .mp4 file in www/resources folder.
When i run ant blackberry load-device ..Number of sign files got increased and signing was successful.

But loading to device gave following error..

```
 [exec] Copyright 2001-2009 Research In Motion Limited
 [exec] Connecting to device...
 [exec] Connected   Loading Test  0 of 
 Error: The specified module was rejected by the device and cannot be loaded
 [exec] 0 bytes sent at ~0 bps
 [exec] Disconnected '
```

Is there any way to package the application with video file.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size of a BlackBerry app [cannot be bigger than 16256 KB](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/The-maximum-size-of-a-BlackBerry-smartphone-application/ta-p/1300209)

If an application exceeds this limit it cannot be installed/run.

I recommend to split your application to two parts. The first part installs on the device, and then downloads video to memory card. Do not use internal filesystem to store large amounts of data. Because internal memory filesystem shares space with critical system modules. And when there is shortage of internal memory, then device goes mad, and may restart itself accidentaly, freeze issues occur, etc.